# VersionOne rest API description attribute format

Tags: api, rest, versionone

Successfully using the VersionOne API to create stories using the REST API. Unfortunately the description field seems to strip all xml tags. (The example online uses

, but this does not work)

So have something like:

```
POST /VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 221

<Asset>
    <Attribute name="Name" act="set">New Story</Attribute>
    <Relation name="Scope" act="set">
        <Asset idref="Scope:0" />
    </Relation>
        <Attribute name="Description" act="set"> 
          <p>first line</p> 
          <p> second line</p>
        </Attribute>
</Asset>
```

Any way to insert formatting? Basically we are using this as a story to test our recently created artifact and want to refer to the defects/stories that are included in the artifact. Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Jon, you'll need to XML-encode the text value of Description.  Two possibilities are:

```
<Asset>
    <Attribute name="Name" act="set">New Story</Attribute>
    <Relation name="Scope" act="set">
        <Asset idref="Scope:0" />
    </Relation>
        <Attribute name="Description" act="set"> 
          &lt;p&gt;first line&lt;/p&gt;
          &lt;p&gt; second line&lt;/p&gt;
        </Attribute>
</Asset>
```

or

```
<Asset>
    <Attribute name="Name" act="set">New Story</Attribute>
    <Relation name="Scope" act="set">
        <Asset idref="Scope:0" />
    </Relation>
        <Attribute name="Description" act="set"><![CDATA[
          <p>first line</p> 
          <p> second line</p>
         ]]></Attribute>
</Asset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use CDATA sections, like this:

```
<Asset>
    <Attribute name="Description" act="set">
    <![CDATA[
        <xml>code goes here</xml>
    ]]>
    </Attribute>
</Asset>
```

When I do this against our public test server: https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/http.html, and POST to the default Scope/0, I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Asset href="/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Scope/0/21470" id="Scope:0:21470">
        <Attribute name="Description">&lt;xml&gt;code goes here&lt;/xml&gt; </Attribute>
</Asset>
```

Does this help?